# scanf() function for single char not working

Tags: c, character, scanf

I am trying to write a simple function `replaceChar` in C to replace the single char `A` which was initialized as 0 in main. When main calls `replaceChar`, it prints `input` as 'b', but after the function, it prints `A` as nothing.

I don't understand why the character input isn't being saved to A. I have tried initializing A as '/0' and " " as well. Is it something to do with pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void replaceChar(char input);

int main () {
    char A = 0;
    replaceChar(A);
    printf("2: %c\n", A);
    return 0;
}

void replaceChar(char input) {
    printf("Enter a single character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    printf("1: %c\n", input);   
}
```

returns:

```
Enter a single character: b
1: b
2:
```

Comment: Assigning a new value to a variable in one function isn't going to change the value of a different variable in another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `input` by value, so when you write into it you're just writing in the copy, not in the original. You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void replaceChar(char input);

int main () {
    char A = 0;
    replaceChar(&A);
    printf("2: %c\n", A);
    return 0;
}

void replaceChar(char *input) {  
    printf("Enter a single character: ");
    scanf(" %c", input);
    printf("1: %c\n", *input);   
}
```